# Java method that returns strings using recursion

Tags: java, string, recursion

Here is my code:

```
private static String recString(final int i) {

return (i>0 ?   i + "." + recString(i-1) : i<0? "." + recString(i+1) : ""  ) ;
}
```

The method should return i dots and the number of dots at begin (example recString(4) returns "4....") when i>0 and just dots when i<=0 (example recString(-4) returns "...."). The condition is that I use just one return line any other modification is not allowed. All I get "4.3.2.1." when I call recString(4). I see where is the problem but cant figure out how to take variable just at the beginning and not change it ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you think you need recursion?  The iterative solution is far more straightforward.

Comment: @JoeC I know, but I have test that I have to pass and it won't pass unless it is done using recursion

Comment: @vucko95 please add this information to your question by editing your question.

Comment: @Turing85 I said in Title that that that has to be done using recursion and wrote that "The condition is that I use just one return line any other modification is not allowed"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for a positive number you have to output the initial number only once, and you can only output that number in the 'positive' branch, you have to leave that 'positive' branch after one iteration.

A possible solution is to negate your number after you output it in your 'positive' branch and then allow the 'negative' branch to finish the job (output all the dots):

```
return (i > 0 ? i + recString(-i) : i < 0 ? "." + recString(i + 1) : "");
```

The initial code of the question author worked for non-negative numbers. The suggested sulution makes it work for positive ones too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I've updated the answer with textual explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If non-recursive solutions are allowed, you can use

```
public static String recString(final int length) {
    return String.format("%d%" + length + "s", length, "").replace(' ', '.');
}
```

Which returns `"1."` for `length = 1`, `"2.."` for `length = 2`, and so on, but fails for `length < 1`. If you also need the non-positive numbers, you can use:

```
public static String recString(final int length) {
    return length < 1
           ? length + ""
           : String.format("%d%" + length + "s", length, "").replace(' ', '.');
}
```

By the way: »*Only one return line*« could also mean that your you are allowed to write functions like the following.

```
public static String recString(final int length) {
    String result;

    // do something

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if `i` value is `>0` `i` is appended to a `StringBuilder` and then `i` dots follow otherwise `i` dots are appended to this `StringBuilder`, finally a `String` is returned from the our `StringBuilder` using `toString` method.

```
private static String recString(final int i) {

            StringBuilder recString= new StringBuilder();

            if (i > 0) {
                recString.append(i);
                for (int x = 0; x < i; x++) {
                    recString.append(".");
                }
            } else {

                for (int x = 0; x > i; x--) 
                    recString.append(".");

            }
            return recString.toString();
        }
```

Comment: An explanation was added.